# Hide Empty attributes and Show Attributes group name

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, ce-1.9.0.1

What is the best way to hide an empty attribute in the front end,  and Display attributes group names if that group has an attribute showing in the front end.

EX:

Group Name

    Attribute: Sample text 

    Attribute: Sample text

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// From product view page (catalog/product/view.phtml)
$attributeSetId = $_product->getAttributeSetId();
$groups = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')
              ->getResourceCollection()
              ->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
              ->setSortOrder()
              ->load();

$groupAttributeValues = array();
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $groupName = $group->getAttributeGroupName();
    $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
                      ->setAttributeGroupFilter($group->getId())
                      ->addVisibleFilter()
                      ->checkConfigurableProducts()
                      ->load();
    if ($attributes->getSize() > 0) {
        foreach ($attributes->getItems() as $attribute) {
            $attributeCode  = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            $attributeLabel = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
            $attributeValue = $_product->getData($attributeCode);
            if ($attributeValue != '') { //check other condition if you want to
                $groupAttributeValues[$groupName][$attributeLabel] = $attributeValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
Zend_Debug::dump($groupAttributeValues);
```